# Lock or Pin java process into memory

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel

Is there a way to lock a java process into memory.

Using something like mlock/mlockall it is possible to lock the memory of a process into memory, so that it doesn't get swapped out. With this approach is it possible to write a C wrapper before invoking the java process to lock the java process into memory? If so, how would the wrapper invoke the java program - fork/clone/vfork/execl?

Or maybe there is some other way to lock a java process into memory?

Thanks,
Parixit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write a wrapper, you can call mlock/mlockall from your Java program using JNI; you don't even have to write/compile the interface code, JNI does it for you.

For further information, see [Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) or [its Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI).