# How To Lock Java Process To Memory? (MLock)

Tags: java, memory, locking, java-native-interface

I found this stack overflow question from 2010:
[Lock or Pin java process into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936027/lock-or-pin-java-process-into-memory)

Basically it says the way to lock a java process to memory is by using JNI.  The example it points to is a broken link.  Now that it's 2013 my question is.. Is there a better way?  And is there an example somewhere of someone using mlock in Java?  I'm extremely inexperienced with JNI and with C code in general, but quite familiar with Java (although I've NEVER used JNI).

Thanks

Comment: My only experience of locking processes in memory dates from 1978 when a colleague did it against everybody's advice and brought the system concerned to its knees. I *strongly* advise you not to do this.

Comment: I want to do it for security reasons.  There is no "system" involved.  Simply a one-time process.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pin the whole process in memory, the entire JVM, or do you just need to ensure some buffer containing, say, a password or other sensitive data, is not swapped out? I don't know the answer, unfortunately, but if you can get away with the latter, I would choose it over the former. The entire JVM process can have a substantial amount of memory associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if there's a good java solution that doesn't involve JNI if possible.

There isn't.  Pinning an application in memory is operating system specific, and not supported by the standard JVM APIs.

---

Pinning a rather dangerous thing to do ... because of the potential for serious impact on overall system performance.  And consequently, it *should* require root privilege (or the equivalent) on any system that supports it.

I personally wouldn't try to do this, and would be very hesitant to use an application that did this.  What ever it is that you are trying to achieve would (probably) better be done in some other way ...

---

> I want to do it for security reasons.

Oh.  So what you are *actually* trying to do is to stop "super secret" stuff being written to the swap/page space on disc?

1. I'm not convinced that mlock would prevent stuff being written to swap.
2. If someone can get access to the swap disc, the chances are that they can use other mechanisms to extract the data; e.g. by using "/dev/mem" or the equivalent to read stuff out of physical memory or the processes virtual memory.
3. The normal way to address the problem of "super secret" stuff on the swap disc is to use char arrays instead of strings to hold the stuff, and manually overwrite them with zeros as soon as they are done with.
4. Or investigate disc-level encryption.

Comment: There is a valid threat model where an attacker can access a disk while the computer is not running but not perform a cold-boot attack.

Comment: @liridayn - OK, maybe. But if that is a realistic thread model, then disc-level encryption solves that far more effectively than any mlock-based solution.  (And without the potential negative consequence of pinning.)

Comment: Depending on implementation, encrypted swap would protect against the same. However, encrypted swap may have a much higher overhead than pinning a single page in memory for a brief time. It also makes the application less portable than an `mlock` solution.

Comment: You can't have it all.  Security against improbable attack vectors involving physical hardware access AND portability AND high performance AND no jni / jna.  Frankly, if the bad guys can get access to your (unencrypted) disks, then your problems are way bigger than can be solved with mlock.  You need to look at the complete picture.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and found this:

https://github.com/LucidWorks/mlockall-agent/

It appears to be a really nice solution to the problem of pinning Java memory. If you use it, make sure that your initial heap size (-XMs) is set to the same as your maximum heap size (-Xmx) - the documentation says that if you don't do this, any memory allocated after the initial heap will not be locked.

Comment: This requires JNA ... according to the README.